# Integral basis and Integral extensions

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have two questions: 
a) How can I find the integral basis of the integral closure of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb  Q(\sqrt{3})$.
b) How can I show that an integral extension is not finite, for example how to show that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\dots,\sqrt[p]{2},\dots)$ is not a finite extension of $\Bbb Q$.
Maybe these questions are easy but I have no idea how to deal with them, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

(1) The elements $\,1\;,\;\sqrt 3\,$ are integral and linearly independent (both over $\,\Bbb Q\,\,\,and\,\,\,\Bbb Z\,$)

(2) For any $\,n\ge 2\;,\;\;x^n-2\,$ is irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q\,$ ...

Comment: For (1), if I am not misunderstanding you, you still need to show that the integral closure is exactly $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the beginning of my post, @Sanchez: these are **hints** and the OP must still complete stuff and work a little,

Comment: @Don, Thank you for your Hints, but I'm really lost, can you say a word or two about how to continue from your hints. Thank you.

Comment: @DonAntonio, sure I know it's a hint, but I am suggesting that your hint may lead to the (easier) side of showing $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ lying in the integral closure, while the more substantial part is to show that it is exactly the integral closure.

Comment: If you read Sanchez's comment then you have the continuation: what's the integral closure of the integers in the number field $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)\,$ ? It's going to be tough if you try to deal with integral basis and stuff without first figuring out what the integral closure is. For (2) it's almsot straightforward: apply Eisenstein's Criterium to prove what I wrote there and then deduce that for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ your extension contains a subextension of degree $\,n\,$ and thus cannot be a finite one...

Comment: @Sanchez, there's a pretty standard way to find out what the integral closure of the integers in a quadratic extension $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)\,\,,\,\,d\in\Bbb Z$ square-free, is (according as whether $\,d=1\,\,or\,\,3\,\pmod 4 \,$ and stuff). I think this must be known at least at the same time, if not before, dealing with this kind of questions.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I would rather think that OP didn't even know about that fact given the way he asks about (1). Different people would have different perspectives on this I suppose.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I don't know how to find the clouser, can you tell me how to start?

Comment: @i.a.m, you can read it in trillions of places (well, I may have exaggerated and perhaps it's only billions). Check the following after googling 10 second:http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uiuc.edu%2F~r-ash%2FAlgebra%2FChapter7.pdf&ei=2wlRUZWIBc2Shgf0roHYBA&usg=AFQjCNFgCvvgsFyg_N4Z5wk22jsy0mbikA&sig2=OGVyWeyD_sQE4ewfH9IF5A&bvm=bv.44342787,bs.1,d.Yms , in 7.2 and forward, page 5. In particular, 7.2.2.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Ok, well do, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Sanchez, Thank you for you comments.

Comment: My pleasure, @i.a.m

Answer (score 3):

Alternative hint for a). Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed, $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is in the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if its polynomial is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The minimal polynomial of $a+b\sqrt{3}$ has coefficients depending on $a$ and $b$--this should give you the necessary conditions.